# How to ignore final blank line when using istream_iterator

Tags: c++, file-io, istream-iterator

Let's say I have a simple text file of 2D points like this:

```
10
0.000   0.010
0.000   0.260
0.000   0.510
0.000   0.760
0.000   1.010
0.000   1.260
0.000   1.510
0.000   1.760
0.000   2.010
0.000   2.260
// Blank line here
```

I use a simple struct for IO:

```
template <typename T>
struct point
{
    point (T x = 0, T y = 0) : x (x), y (y) {}

    T x ;
    T y ;

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &is, point &p) {
        is >> p.x >> p.y ;
        return is ;
    }
};
```

My original code was:

```
int main (void)
{
    std::string strFile = "Points.txt" ;

    std::ifstream file ;
    file.exceptions (std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit) ;
    std::vector <point <double> > vec ;

    try {
        file.open (strFile) ;

        int nPoints = 0 ;
        file >> nPoints ;

        for (int n = 0; n < nPoints; ++n) {
            point <double> p ;
            file >> p ;
            vec.push_back (p) ;
        }
    }

    catch (std::ios_base::failure &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what () << "\n" ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

This works fine, but in the spirit of [no raw loops](http://www.codestrokes.com/2013/11/sean-parent-no-raw-loops/), I'd like to get rid of the for-loop.

Here is my new code:

```
int main (void)
{
    std::string strFile = "Points.txt" ;

    std::ifstream file ;
    file.exceptions (std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit) ;
    std::vector <point <double> > vec ;

    try {
        file.open (strFile) ;

        int nPoints = 0 ;
        file >> nPoints ;

        std::copy (
            std::istream_iterator <point <double> > (file), 
            std::istream_iterator <point <double> > (), 
            std::back_inserter (vec)
        ) ;
    }

    catch (std::ios_base::failure &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what () << "\n" ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Everything is copied fine, but unfortunately, reading the final blank line causes the fail-bit to be set.

The only ways I can think of fixing this are kind of ugly. I could:

- Put a try-catch clause in the `point::operator>>()` function
- Check `vec.size()` in the catch clause that already exists.

Is there an elegant way of ignoring the final blank line?

Comment: Just out of curiosity does anyone know WHY it sets the failbit when iot prints the blank line?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I have an `std::istream_iterator` of `point <double>`s. When it calls the `point::operator>>` on the blank line, the fail-bit is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
    std::copy (
        std::istream_iterator <point <double> > (file), 
        std::istream_iterator <point <double> > (), 
        std::back_inserter (vec)
    ) ;
```

to

```
    std::copy_n (
        std::istream_iterator <point <double> > (file), 
        nPoints, 
        std::back_inserter (vec)
    ) ;
```

Comment: @jliv902 usually the ordinary while loop is used.

Comment: @0x499602D2 AFAIK function std::copy_n was added in C++ 11.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Right. Thanks. Some online documentation needs to be clarified.

Comment: This sadly doesn't work when there is no equivalent of `nPoints`.

Comment: @intelfx  Whar do you mean by "no equivalent of nPoints"?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow when the input stream does not contain explicit count of data-sets, i. e. when the program shall read input just until EOF.

Comment: @intelf You are right. In general case it is needed to check whether there is data in the file.